# Month Calendar C#

Tags: c#, calendar

i am making a monthly calender but i need it to be set to a certain year. I am using Visual Studios 2013 and coding in C#. My code i've tried is

```
monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString(2013 - 06 - 04);
```

My problem is that i cannot find code that will set the date to what i want when it loads. I would like to make it start up and have the date set to April, 06, 2013.

Comment: Any unexpected behavior / problem / errors?

Comment: Please clarify your problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Have you read the [documentation on `ToShortDateString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) to see what it does?

Comment: What happened when you tried to compile the code you are showing? Did you get a compiler error message? Have you **read it**?

Comment: What do you believe the minus sign does?

Comment: Even if the code doesn't work, it still helps if we can see it. Please put it into your post.

Comment: For accurately helping you, we need to know **what you tried** (in this case, your current code), **why it didn't work** (error messages?) and **why you thought it was going to work** (an explanation of your own understanding of what you wrote).

Comment: In other words: Could you please explain step by step how you think the code you are showing achieves "have the date set to April, 06, 2013"? I'm not asking for this to give you a headache, but because I'd like to help you starting from "where you are".

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code sample — **does it even compile?** — doesn't do what you think it does. The expression `2013 - 06 - 04` is an *integer expression* that evaluates to the integer value `2003` (2013 less 6 is 2007; 2007 less 4 is 2003).

Assuming you're using `System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar`, the property `SelectionStart` is a `DateTime` value. Your code is trying to take that property's current value and convert it to a string using the current culture's short date format (M/d/yyyy for 'en-US'). Then you're throwing that string away. And `ToShortDateString()` doesn't take any arguments so you're almost certainly getting a compiler whine.

If you're trying to *set* the selection start, you might try something along the lines of:

```
monthCalendar1.SelectionStart = new DateTime(2013,4,6) ; // 6 April, 2013
```

You could then set the selection end to something appropriate. For instance:

```
monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd = monthCalendar.SelectionStart.AddDays(7) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.selectionstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Set the date range:

```
this.MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart = 
        new System.DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, vacationMonth, today.Day-1);
this.MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd = 
        new System.DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, vacationMonth, today.Day+6);
```

Set the default date:

```
this.MonthCalendar1.TodayDate = new System.DateTime(Year, Month, Day);
```

Comment: Just some code for copying and pasting will rather not help the OP understand what they did wrong in their own attempt at solving this, and even if it "helps" now by providing a ready-made solution, it will not help the OP in similar situations, nor will it help any future visitors who have a similar, but not the same problem.